# How to securly save client_id and client_secret in OAUTH Client Credential Flow

Tags: oauth

In the application I make use of the client credential flow to make requests. I am unsure about how to save the client_id and client_secret. Right now I have them in a seperate file but I am not sure what encoding should be done. This is the code:

```
response = requests.post(access_url,
                         data=f"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client.client_id}&client_secret={client.client_secret}&scope={scope}",
                         headers={'accept': "application/json", 'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
```

Comment: The application (== the Oauth client) that you are building, is running on client side?

Comment: There are several ways. One way is to save those in a file with restricted permissions. Another alternative is to use a secret management system such as Hashicorp Vault.

Comment: If your client is an app running in a browser, then do not use a confidential client (it is use less).

Comment: @user3467955 Yes it is running on client side!